# Add cell A to cell B and reset cell A to 0

Tags: excel, vba

I need to add cell A to cell B of the same row and then reset cell A to zero. I did some searching and found this code that works perfectly, but I need to have it work for an entire column not just one row.

So, all of column A should add to column B,  but only on the same row. Here is the code I found:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Address = Range("a1").Address Then
        Range("b1") = Range("b1") + Range("a1")
        Range("a1").ClearContents
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

And:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        Dim A1 As Range
        Set A1 = Range("A1")
        If Intersect(Target, A1) Is Nothing Then
        Else
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            With A1
                .Offset(0, 1) = .Offset(0, 1) + .Value
                .ClearContents
            End With
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

Both sets of code work just fine to add cell A to B and reset A to zero, but I want this to work for the entire (column A and B) and all by row.

[image]

That is a picture of what I would like. I hope that this was clear and easy to understand. I appreciate any help that anyone can provide. I really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Here is a link that has the code I found. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22226136/add-value-from-one-cell-to-another-then-reset-cell-value-excel

Comment: in your second code change 1) `Set A1 = Range("A1")` to `Set A1 = Range("A:A")`, 2) `With A1` to `With Target` - should help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim T As Range, r As Range
    Set T = Intersect(Target, Range("A:A"))
    If T Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each r In T
        With r
            .Offset(0, 1).Value = .Offset(0, 1).Value + .Value
            .ClearContents
        End With
    Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you so much, I really do appreciate it.